# Currency format in value return?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a PHP script that SUMED up one column.  However, the number is not formatted correctly.

OK -> ฿4,192.00
Not OK -> Injected: ฿148000

How can I add the thousand separator (commas) in the script itself?

```
function total_loaned() {
global $wpdb; 

$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(wp_wpdatatable_1.totalloanamount) 
as sumed FROM wp_wpdatatable_1");

foreach( $users as $user ) {
echo '<span style="color:#fff;text-align:center;font-size:12px">Injected: ฿' 
. $user->sumed;

}

}
add_shortcode('fp_total_loaned', 'total_loaned');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `number_format` to achieve this:

```
echo number_format($user->sumed, 2, '.', ',');
```